# More than 3 team projects in TFS 2012 web portal?

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access, tfs-2012

In the TFS 2012 web portal, when I click the team project name at the top, I see the most recent 3 team projects I have browsed available, along with options for Server Home and Browse. Now, I can just choose Browse and pick a team project if it's not in the list of 3, but is it possible to configure this to show more than 3 team projects?

I like the one-click option, but often, the team project I want was more than 3 projects ago, so I end up having to Browse and scroll and select it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, there might be some hack to do it, but looking in the database, it only stores 3 team's in the MRU list in the database.

Best bet would be to raise a [UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/) request for it.